# Conditional styling of a DataFrame using another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I have two 3X3 pandas DataFrames `df1`

```
    A   B   C
0   8   3   9
1   1   7   7
2   3   3   8
```

and `df2`.

```
    A   B   C
0   2   1   2
1   5   9   7
2   1   8   3
```

What I want to obtain is a tabulated Jupyter Notebook output whose elements are the same as `df1` but their font color is red if the element value is greater than the corresponding value of `df2`.
Thus, the expected output is something like the following

```
    A     B     C
0   8(r)  3(r)  9(r)
1   1     7     7 
2   3(r)  3     8(r)
```

`(r)` means the font color of the cell is red, not real printout.

What I tried was `applymap` method like this

```
df1.style.applymap(lambda x: 'color : red' if x > df2 else '')
```

but could not figure out how to set `labmda x` and `df2` on an equal footing.
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should create a DataFrame of styles then [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) on `axis=None`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [8, 1, 3], 'B': [3, 7, 3], 'C': [9, 7, 8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 5, 1], 'B': [1, 9, 8], 'C': [2, 7, 3]})
```

Option 1: compare and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
style_df = (
        df1 > df2                  # Compare DataFrames
).replace({
    True: 'background-color:red',  # True Styles
    False: ''                      # False Styles
})

df1.style.apply(lambda _: style_df, axis=None)
```

Or by creating the style DataFrame directly in the apply call:

```
df1.style.apply(lambda _: (df1 > df2).replace({
    True: 'background-color:red',
    False: ''
}), axis=None)
```

---

Option 2: perhaps more performant, but less idiomatic is [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df1.style.apply(lambda _: np.where(
    df1 > df2,               # Compare DataFrames
    'background-color:red',  # True Styles
    ''                       # False Styles
), axis=None)
```

---

Both produce styled table:

[image: styled df]

How the styling is determined with `style_df`:

```
                      A                     B                     C
0  background-color:red  background-color:red  background-color:red
1                                                                  
2  background-color:red                        background-color:red
```